# $and combined with 2dsphere in mongo/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get this code to work (node+mongoose)

```
model.find({
        $and: [
            { 'location': { $near: { $geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [lat, long]}  }, $maxDistance: 1000 }},
            {'status': { $size: 1 }}
        ]
    },
```

and keep on getting

> can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs
>   index),  for: { $and: [ { location: { $near: { $geometry: { type:
>   "Point", coordinates: [ 12.5386, 41.884 ] } }, $maxDistance: 1000 } },
>   { status: { $size: 1 } } ] }

i do have my indexes in place with mongo

```
{
    "location" : "2dsphere"
}
```

what am i missing? 
many thanks.

**EDIT : adding document structure**

```
{
    "name" : "Frag",
    "desc" : "Frag",
    "host" : ObjectId("534047663164711f7e7a952f"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("535d7d8b454017f874de2d42"),
    "status" : [ 
        {
            "state" : "created",
            "_id" : ObjectId("535d7d8b454017f874de2d43"),
            "date" : ISODate("2014-04-27T21:58:35.406Z")
        }
    ],
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("534047663164711f7e7a952f")
    ],
    "location" : [ 
        32.0652823, 
        34.7767135
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: $and is implied in all MongoDB queries. You do not need to specify that as a wrapper. Show the document in your question maybe. Is `location` actually a top level field?

Comment: Sure. Where is "location"? It's not in your document. Since this looks like you have lots of references here is it actually in another collection? Even if you specified the correct path to that other collection document you could not do this query unless that data was embedded. Seems like you need to understand the limitation of Mongoose populate and what it can actually do. Or not do as is the likely case.

Comment: whoops my bad. wrong copy paste, but i did notice that some of my documents are lacking a "location" might this be the problem? though it is weird bc if i do not include the "status.size" in the find it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong here in that you are specifying GeoJSON co-ordinate mapping for something you actually have defined as "legacy co-ordinate pairs" and there is a big difference between the two.

Certainly what you should be doing (your data on my collection called docs):

```js
db.docs.find({ 
    "location": { 
        "$near": [12.5386, 41.884], 
        "$maxDistance": 1000
    },
    "status": { "$size": 1 }
})
```

But this is failing unless I actually change the index type to "2d" instead:

```js
db.docs.dropIndexes();
db.docs.ensureIndex({ "location": "2d" })
```

Then you get the result of your document as you are expecting.

This is by design as a "2dsphere" index is designed for data in GeoJSON format, from the documentation:

> The [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator requires a geospatial index: a 2dsphere index for GeoJSON points; a 2d index for legacy coordinate pairs. By default, queries that use a 2d index return a limit of 100 documents; however you may use limit() to change the number of results.

If you want a "2dsphere" index then your co-ordinates data needs to change:

```js
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            32.0652823, 
            34.7767135
        ]
    }
```

But the immediate "workaround" is clearly to use a "2d" index instead, and of course change your syntax as I have shown.

Comment: this is weird; I've added the 
**{"location" : "2d"}** and used the query you suggested but now the 
$maxdistance doesnt work at all! it always returns all the documents filtered only by status.size, is this a bug too?

FYI im on 2.4.3.

Comment: @Pavel'PK'Kaminsky `$maxdistance` is a typo. Should be `$maxDistance`. Also check that you actually have points outside the range you are requesting. But I cannot reproduce. The index type is by design. See the further notes in the answer.